Database dump of this site is detected as malware
The latest database dump of this site is detected as malware, which has caused it to be automatically removed from Stack Exchange's archive.org page. The last database dump, in December 2021 didn't have any issues, so the problem was probably introduced in the last 3 months.
So: any ideas what post is causing the database dump for this site to be flagged as malware?

Oh, this isn't new.

Seemingly they hope to address it in an upcoming dump, i.e. they're working on it.
Another option which comes in handy on a smartphone is https://download.kiwix.org/zim/stack_exchange/ ... but the dumps of individual sites appear at irregular intervals. Plenty of mirrors exist, too ... such as here. An overview can be found on their Wiki. But it's obviously no replacement for the full SQL dump.
